# Sort Categories filters alphabetically for search results

Tags: magento-1.9, category, search, sorting

I want to sort the category filters alphabetically by name on my search results page.

[image]

Most answers suggest setting the position for every category. However, this seems rather manual. Is there another way to sort the category filters? Ideally through an option?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it through an option, but you could do it through code.

You would need to get access to the category collection by extending the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` class and overriding the `getCurrentChildCategories()` function to call `setOrder('name')` on `$this->_currentChildCategories` prior to returning it.

Comment: Keep in mind I am talking about the search results filters and not the category navigation.

Comment: Ah, I have the wrong block listed there, but the concept is right. I'll find the correct block later today and update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by editing/extending core code. However, I always like to avoid editing/extending core code.

You can go to `catalog > category > manage categories` section and re-adjust by pulling down/up as needed manually.

This will sort your categories. I know this is time consuming, but this is needed only once. After this, if you add any new category in future, just need to re-adjust that new one only.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Op specifically asked for another way to do it than what you suggest.

Comment: Sure he did @JoeConstant, however you should always show them better way and magento way. There are always diff ways of doing things. Hope you understand that. Cheers.

Comment: I don't disagree with the approach (manually sorting it once now). However, there is nothing wrong with wanting to do it another way.

Comment: Keep in mind I am talking about the search results filters and not the category navigation.

Comment: Sure, I believe it works for your search results as well. Give it a try.